# SQL - Retrieve records based on parameters where either parameter can be null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure which takes in five parameters of which two can be null - we will call these parameters A and B

What I would like to do is select records based on the following logic.

If Parameter A is NULL then only return records that match Parameter B

I know that I can do something similar to the following

```
  IF A IS NULL 
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Param=B    
    END
    ELSE
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Param=A    
END
```

However, the SQL query is much more complex then the above one and there would be huge replication in the Proc which is something I want to avoid

Thanks in advance

===============================

EDIT - Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the example the Param are based on separate columns e.g.

My table consists of four columns of which two separate columns map to the two parameters - basic schema below

ID
PersonName
GroupID
DeliveryID

In my procedure I want to retrieve those records that match the GroupID *however* in the scenario where the GroupID is null then I want to return those records that match the DeliveryID

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, something like this should work.  If either parameter is `NULL`, the condition becomes a self-identity (assuming neither `groupID` nor `deliveryID` is NULL).

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE groupID    = coalesce(@groupIDParameter, groupID)
   AND deliveryID = coalesce(@deliveryIDParameter, deliveryID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Param = COALESCE(A,B)
```

`COALESCE` will give you `A` if it's not null. Otherwise `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Try ISNULL function:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Param = ISNULL(B,A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a case statement Case when A is Null Then B